# DataForm Control like in SL3 for WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, dataform

Im looking for a control like the DataForm which is new in Silverlight 3 for handling the whole binding and validation logic (declarativly with property attributes etc) for WPF.

I always thought of SL as a subset of WPF but there seems to bee no DataForm control, at least not in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace like in SL (I know SL uses another CLR)

Have I overlooked something? Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most (if not all) of the new stuff in SL3 will end up in WPF 4 when .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 ship. The DataForm should be included. With SL2 Microsoft started to ship some features in SL before WPF. This seems to continue in for the current release cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Check out

http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=57614

http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

The code is available here http://www.rudigrobler.net/Blog/will-the-real-dataform-please-stand-up (This includes both the Desktop and Silverlight versions for comparison)

The page has moved to: http://rudigroblerwp.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/will-the-real-dataform-please-stand-up/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout, this is available on WPF as well as Silverlight...

http://uiatoms.neurospeech.com/parent-page/form-controls/

Comment: yeah but unlike the silverlight dataform, that one cost$